# ¿Que es el parámetro de indexación en C#?

Tags: c#

He descubierto que en C#, se puede obtener un caracter de un string por su posición haciendo lo siguiente:

```
string prueba = "Hola";
char extracto = prueba[2]; //Donde extracto contendría la letra 'l'
```

Porque es esto?

Como funciona esto?

Puedo yo también hacerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto se debe a que la clase `String` que es un alias de `string` en C#, tiene una propiedad indexadora:

```
public sealed class String : //Extiende e implementa clases e interfaces
{
   public char this[int index]
   {
      //Código
   }
}
```

Y así mismo se pueden crear propiedades indexadoras en nuestras clases que se refieran a la clase misma mediante `this`:

```
public class MiClase
{
   string[] cadenas = new string[]{"Hola", "Mundo"};

   public string this[int indice]
   {
      return cadenas[indice];
   }
}
```

Para referenciarlos...

```
MiClase miclase = new MiClase();
string extracto = miclase[1];
```

Como ves, `this` te evita tener que crear un nombre adicional de propiedad ya que la clase **literalmente** se convierte en dicha propiedad y retorna el tipo de dato que hayas declarado.

Puedes usar varios tipos de datos:

```
public char this[int indice]...
public double this[string palabra]...
public object this[bool escribir]...
```

Pero la cosa no acaba aquí, no solo estás limitado a usar un solo parámetro '`[int index]`' sino que puedes usar varios:

```
public double this[double numero1, double numero2, double numero3, double numeroN]
{
    return numero1 + numero2 + numero3 + numeroN;
}
```

Y aunque todas las propiedades sean this, si los parámetros entre los corchetes son diferentes, serán tratadas como propiedades independientes donde:

```
public class MiClase
{
   string[] cadenas = new string[]{"Hola", "Mundo"};

   //Esto es una propiedad
   public string this[int indice]
   {
      return cadenas[indice];
   }

   //Esto es otra
   public int this[bool booleano]
   {
      return (!booleano) ? 0 : 1;
   }

   //Y esto es otra
   public double this[double numero1, double numero2, double numero3, double numeroN]
   {
      return numero1 + numero2 + numero3 + numeroN;
   }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que si lo haces así, el compilador las distinguira por sus parametros, o sea que si escribes:

```
string prueba = miclase[1]; //Este sera la primera propiedad
int prueba2 = miclase[true]; //Este sera la segunda propiedad y sucesivamente
```

Espero te sirva a tí, y a futuros lectores, suerte.